# JSqlParser how to split an Expression

Tags: java, sql, visitor-pattern, sql-parser

Suppose I have an expression of the format

```
a>10 and b>20 and c>30
```

I want to get a list of expressions as follows

```
a>10
b>20
c>30
```

If I use the expression visitor pattern, for the AndExpression visitor, I wrote something like

```
public void visit(AndExpression andExpression) {
    andExpression.getLeftExpression().accept(this);
    andExpression.getRightExpression().accept(this);
}
```

but this however recursively runs and goes into each of the other visitor pattern methods. How do I stop when a smaller expression is obtained?

If i just use getLeftExpressions() and getRightExpression(), what I get in the first run is "a>10" as the left and "b>20 and c>30" as the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `visit` method, you can return a list of `Expression` for a given `And` expressions. So just return a list of `Expression` object as follows:

```
public List<Expression> visit(AndExpression andExpression) {
    List<Expression> list = new ArrayList<Expression>();
    lex = andExpression.getLeftExpression();
    list.add(lex);
    rex = andExpression.getRightExpression();
    subEx1 = rex.getLeftExpression();
    subEx2 = rex.getRightExpression();
    list.add(subEx1);
    list.add(subEx2);
    return list;
}
```

The two sub-expressions are obtained from the first right expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What changes when I have to do it recursively? For multiple expressions?

Comment: @Archana You can do a while loop to iterate over the expression to get all subexpressions, like `while(ex.getLeftExpression() != null) {list.add(ex.getLeftExpression()); ex = ex.getRightExpression();}`.

Answer (score 3):

JSqlParser parses your expression in this way:

```
AndExpression
   AndExpression
       a>10
       b>20
   c>30
```

I am curious to see which version you use, if the recursion will be indeed in the right item not the left. I use [JSqlParser 0.9-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser). Nevertheless in my version of **JSqlParser** (and I think in all, because it is an LL parser), the in the other answers comment proposed codeblock

```
while(ex.getLeftExpression() != null) {
    list.add(ex.getLeftExpression()); 
    ex = ex.getRightExpression();
}
```

will not work. It finds (or collects):

```
a > 10 AND b > 20
```

which is an `AndExpression` and fails on `ex = ex.getRightExpression();`, because the right
will never be an `AndExpression`. That is how JSqlParser works. The `AndExpression` recursion would be in the `leftExpression`.

So here is a solution and a litte test around it, using **JSqlParser V0.9-SNAPSHOT**, which uses the recursive way to visit these `AndExpressions` and prints out the found expression. I did not add it to a `List`. Forgive me for that.

```
public class JSqlParser1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSQLParserException {
        Expression expr = CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression("a>10 and b>20 and c>30");
        expr.accept(new ExpressionVisitorAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void visit(AndExpression expr) {
                if (expr.getLeftExpression() instanceof AndExpression) {
                    expr.getLeftExpression().accept(this);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(expr.getLeftExpression());
                }

                System.out.println(expr.getRightExpression());
            }

        });
    }
}
```

This one prints:

```
a > 10
b > 20
c > 30
```